# test if jQuery library is loaded and the '$ is not defined' error

Tags: jquery

in my .js file which will be using by external users I want to check if on their's page the jQuery lubrary is loaded. To do so, I'm using:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}    

$(document).ready(function () {
    //do some jquery $.ajax({}); stuff
});
```

but, at the `$(document).ready(function () {` line I get the error message `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` How to fix it ?

### edit:

I've added the line

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    ...
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild("<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function () {...});</script>");
}
```

and now I get the `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLHeadElement.appendChild]`

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the script you append is loaded asynchronously, so you could add an `onload` handler to the script element and run your other code from that handler. But even ignoring that issue, note that if the external user may already have a different version of jQuery, i.e., an old one that doesn't necessarily support all the functionality you need, and the user may also have called `jQuery.noConflict()`...

Comment: Reference your files in the correct order Jquery.js first and then your js

Comment: You're right, but I want to invoke some code after that asynchronous library loading is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the document.ready part, and, in a separate script tag beneath the one you are using to append jQuery to the head, do this:

```
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
   //do the same code in here as you would've done in document.ready
 }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

The comment below makes a good point...in that case, you do this:

```
<script>
 (function() {
     var load = function() {
       //do the same code in here as you would've done in document.ready
     };

     if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load',load);
     } else {
        window.attachEvent('onload',load);
     }
 }());
</script>
```

Comment: What if window.onload is already used somewhere on the external site?

Answer (score 1):

In such cases people are usually asked to try something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)...
If you do not want to use it, you can try to set your own handlers to catch the moment when jquery finishes loading.

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    var loadHandlerAlreadyRun = false;
    script.onload = function() {
        if (!loadHandlerAlreadyRun) {
           loadHandlerAlreadyRun = true;
           onLoadHandler();
        }
    };
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (!loadHandlerAlreadyRun && (this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete")) {
            loadHandlerAlreadyRun = true;
            onLoadHandler();
        }
    }
}    

function onLoadHandler() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("jquery loaded");
        //do some jquery $.ajax({}); stuff
    });

}
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4n5D4/)

Answer (score 0):

you can check with code :

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
if( window.jQuery === undefined ) {
    //create script tag for appending script source
    var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
    //check for IE
    if( scriptTag.readyState ) {
        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if( scriptTag.readyState == 'loaded' || scriptTag.readyState == 'complete' ) {
                scriptTag.onreadystatechange = null;
                scriptHandler();
            }
        };
    }
    else {
        scriptTag.onload = function() {
            scriptHandler();
        };
    }
    scriptTag.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js";
    ( document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement ).appendChild( scriptTag );
}
else {
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    process();
}

function scriptHandler() {
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict( true );
    process();
}
function process() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //use $ here
    });
}
```